# Pandas advanced problem : For each row, get complex info from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### Problem

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
Index  Client_ID   Date   
1      johndoe     2019-01-15
2      johndoe     2015-11-25
3      pauldoe     2015-05-26
```

And I have another dataframe `df_prod`, with products like this :

```
Index   Product-Type   Product-Date   Buyer     Price
1       A              2020-01-01     pauldoe   300
2       A              2018-01-01     pauldoe   200
3       A              2019-01-01     johndoe   600
4       A              2017-01-01     johndoe   800
5       A              2020-11-05     johndoe   100
6       B              2014-12-12     johndoe   200
7       B              2016-11-15     johndoe   300
```

What I want is to add to `df` a column, that will sum the Prices of the last products of each type known at the current date (with `Product-Date <= df.Date`). An example is the best way to explain :

For the first row of `df`

```
1      johndoe     2019-01-01
```

The last A-Product known at this date bought by `johndoe` is this one :

```
3       A              2019-01-01     johndoe   600
```

(since the 4th one is older, and the 5th one has a `Product-Date` > `Date`)
The last B-Product known at this date bought by `johndoe` is this one :

```
7       B              2016-11-15     johndoe   300
```

So the row in `df`, after transformation, will look like that (`900` being `600 + 300`, prices of the 2 products of interest) :

```
1      johndoe     2019-01-15   900
```

The full `df` after transformation will then be :

```
Index  Client_ID   Date         LastProdSum
1      johndoe     2019-15-01   900
2      johndoe     2015-11-25   200
3      pauldoe     2015-05-26   0
```

As you can see, there are multiple possibilities :

- Buyers didn't necessary buy all products (see `pauldoe`, who only bought A-products)
- Sometimes, no product is known at `df.Date` (see row 3 of the new `df`, in 2015, we don't know any product bought by `pauldoe`)
- Sometimes, only one product is known at `df.Date`, and the value is the one of the product (see row 3 of the new `df`, in 2015, we only have one product for `johndoe`, which is a B-product bought in 2014, whose price is `200`)

### What I did :

I found a solution to this problem, but it's taking too much time to be used, since my dataframe is huge.

For that, I iterate using iterrows on rows of `df`, I then select the products linked to the Buyer, having `Product-Date < Date` on `df_prod`, then get the older grouping by `Product-Type` and getting the max date, then I finally sum all my products prices.
The fact I solve the problem iterating on each row (with a for iterrows), extracting for each row of `df` a part of `df_prod` that I work on to finally get my sum, makes it really long.
I'm almost sure there's a better way to solve the problem, with pandas functions (`pivot` for example), but I couldn't find the way. I've been searching a lot.

Thanks in advance for your help

### Edit after Dani's answer

Thanks a lot for your answer. It looks really good, I accepted it since you spent a lot of time on it.
Execution is still pretty long, since I didn't specify something.
In fact, `Product-Types` are not shared through buyers : each buyers has its own multiple products types. The true way to see this is like this :

```
Index   Product-Type   Product-Date   Buyer     Price
1       pauldoe-ID1    2020-01-01     pauldoe   300
2       pauldoe-ID1    2018-01-01     pauldoe   200
3       johndoe-ID2    2019-01-01     johndoe   600
4       johndoe-ID2    2017-01-01     johndoe   800
5       johndoe-ID2    2020-11-05     johndoe   100
6       johndoe-ID3    2014-12-12     johndoe   200
7       johndoe-ID3    2016-11-15     johndoe   300
```

As you can understand, product types are not shared through different buyers (in fact, it can happen, but in really rare situations that we won't consider here)

The problem remains the same, since you want to sum prices, you'll add the prices of last occurences of johndoe-ID2 and johndoe-ID3 to have the same final result row

```
1      johndoe     2019-15-01   900
```

But as you now understand, there are actually more `Product-Types` than `Buyers`, so the step "get unique product types" from your answer, that looked pretty fast on the initial problem, actually takes **a lot** of time.

Sorry for being unclear on this point, I didn't think of a possibility of creating a new df based on product types.

Comment: There is a problem with your date format, you cannot have: 2019-15-01 and 2015-11-25

Comment: Edited. That's my bad. This is not an exact example since I'm not allowed to share my data so i created it by my own. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to fetch the last date for each *Product-Type* and *Client_ID*, so do the following:

```
# get unique product types
product_types = list(df_prod['Product-Type'].unique())

# create a new DataFrame with a row for each Product-Type for each Client_ID
df['Product-Type'] = [product_types for _ in range(len(df))]
df_with_prod = df.explode('Product-Type')

# merge only the closest date by each client and product type
merge = pd.merge_asof(df_with_prod.sort_values(['Date', 'Client_ID']),
                      df_prod.sort_values(['Product-Date', 'Buyer']),
                      left_on='Date',
                      right_on='Product-Date',
                      left_by=['Client_ID', 'Product-Type'], right_by=['Buyer', 'Product-Type'])

# fill na in prices
merge['Price'] = merge['Price'].fillna(0)

# sum Price by client and date
res = merge.groupby(['Client_ID', 'Date'], as_index=False)['Price'].sum().rename(columns={'Price' : 'LastProdSum'})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Client_ID       Date  LastProdSum
0   johndoe 2015-11-25        200.0
1   johndoe 2019-01-15        900.0
2   pauldoe 2015-05-26          0.0
```

The problem is that *merge_asof* won't work with duplicate values, so we need to create unique values. These new values are the cartesian product of *Client_ID* and *Product-Type*, this part is done in:

```
# get unique product types
product_types = list(df_prod['Product-Type'].unique())

# create a new DataFrame with a row for each Product-Type for each Client_ID
df['Product-Type'] = [product_types for _ in range(len(df))]
df_with_prod = df.explode('Product-Type')
```

Finally do a groupby and sum the *Price*, not before doing a *fillna* to fill the missing values.

**UPDATE**

You could try:

```
# get unique product types
product_types = df_prod.groupby('Buyer')['Product-Type'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

# create a new DataFrame with a row for each Product-Type for each Client_ID
df['Product-Type'] = df['Client_ID'].map(product_types)
df_with_prod = df.explode('Product-Type')

# merge only the closest date by each client and product type
merge = pd.merge_asof(df_with_prod.sort_values(['Date', 'Client_ID']),
                      df_prod.sort_values(['Product-Date', 'Buyer']),
                      left_on='Date',
                      right_on='Product-Date',
                      left_by=['Client_ID', 'Product-Type'], right_by=['Buyer', 'Product-Type'])

# fill na in prices
merge['Price'] = merge['Price'].fillna(0)

# sum Price by client and date
res = merge.groupby(['Client_ID', 'Date'], as_index=False)['Price'].sum().rename(columns={'Price' : 'LastProdSum'})

print(res)
```

The idea here is to change how you generate the *unique* values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It looks really good. I still have an issue, due to the fact I simplified a bit my real problem to avoid this post being too complicated. I edited to add my new issue to the question.

Comment: @BeamsAdept Updated the answer